# Android | Get file (.zip) and save it

Tags: java, android

In my app, I would to open a (.zip) file from my external storage and save it in internal app storage.

To open file, I use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select"), requestCode);
```

Than, I try to use it with:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 7 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Log.d("IMPORT","Start Process");
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        File file = new File(uri.getPath());
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        //some function

        //error:
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(path);
    }
}
```

Now, with function `InputStream is = new FileInputStream(path);` I return `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/primary:Download/example/file.zip: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`.

I've not problems when I save the images, but I never saved a zip file.

Answer (score 4):

> To open file, I use:

First, that does not open a file. That requests access to a piece of content.

Second, if you want ZIP files, you might wish to use `application/zip`, instead of `*/*`. Otherwise, users are welcome to choose something other than a ZIP file.

> I've not problems when I save the images

If you are using the same code as you are using above, then your code will not work for most Android devices, whether for images, ZIP files, or anything else.

[A `Uri` is not a file.](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html)

A `Uri` is an opaque handle to some piece of content, held in some other app. To use that `Uri`, get a `ContentResolver` from a nearby `Context` (e.g., your `Activity`). Then, use `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content.

*If* the `Uri` *happens* to have a `file` scheme, then `getPath()` will be a filesystem path. However:

- You may not have access to that file
- Most of the time, on newer Android devices, the `Uri` will not have a `file` scheme (in particular, [in the N Developer Preview, the `file` scheme is](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html) banned, in effect)

Comment: First of all, thanks. - Okay. - I'm not use same code, but I only meant that I've not problems with permission, sorry. - You can do a part of code for take a file from external storage and put it on internal..?